# spark streaming-Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-40"

Tags: apache-spark, streaming

I am using spark 1.6.
When I run streaming application for a few minutes,it cause such Exception Like this:

```
 Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-40" Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-33" Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-23" Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-14" Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-29" Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-39" Exception in thread "submit-job-thread-pool-2" java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.awaitResult(JobWaiter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction.org$apache$spark$SimpleFutureAction$$awaitResult(FutureAction.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction$$anon$1.run(FutureAction.scala:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    ... 2 more
java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at       java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
    Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.awaitResult(JobWaiter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction.org$apache$spark$SimpleFutureAction$$awaitResult(FutureAction.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction$$anon$1.run(FutureAction.scala:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    ... 2 more
java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.awaitResult(JobWaiter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction.org$apache$spark$SimpleFutureAction$$awaitResult(FutureAction.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction$$anon$1.run(FutureAction.scala:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    ... 2 more
java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.awaitResult(JobWaiter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction.org$apache$spark$SimpleFutureAction$$awaitResult(FutureAction.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction$$anon$1.run(FutureAction.scala:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    ... 2 more
java.lang.Error: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1148)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.lang.InterruptedException
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:502)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.JobWaiter.awaitResult(JobWaiter.scala:73)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction.org$apache$spark$SimpleFutureAction$$awaitResult(FutureAction.scala:165)
    at org.apache.spark.SimpleFutureAction$$anon$1.run(FutureAction.scala:147)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    ... 2 more
```

This problem is so wield,the consume speed is enough.My batch time is 20s, and the first few minutes(app is ok),the process time is 8s. But After that,the Exception will appear.
The input partitions is 1500, the executor is 400,and spark cores is 4.

Comment: How are you running your job? Usually an `InterruptedException` is caused by the you aborting the job, perhaps unwillingly from the command line by mistake.

Comment: Running job with cluster mode like this `../../bin/spark-submit --master yarn-cluster \
     --files logback.xml \
     --driver-memory 20g \
     --num-executors 400 \
     --executor-memory 8g \
     --executor-cores 4 \
     --driver-cores 6 \
     --queue spark-test \
     --class com.baidu.di.MapFlow ./target/di.core.index-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar `

Comment: Can you get any exception from a worker? You can look at yarn web ui

Comment: no exception found in worker.

Comment: I got the same error. Any ideas?